# WooCommerce - Limiting Variations if One is Selected

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My friend and I are launching a furniture store using Wordpress + WooCommerce and we are having a difficulty.

I'm not really sure what would be the best way to explain the challenge that we are having, but would it be possible to limit the number of variations if a particular variation has been selected?

Here's what I mean. My friend wants to sell a bed and it contains a headboard and bedbase. There are three sizes of headboards and bedbases: small, small double, double.

Our attributes currently look like this:

HEADBOARD: NO HEADBOARD | SINGLE HEADBOARD | SMALL DOUBLE | DOUBLE
BEDBASE: SINGLE BEDBASE | SMALL DOubLE BEDBASE | DOUBLE BEDBASE

Is there a plugin or a way to limit the variation shown. Let's say a customer selects a single headboard and he would only see single bedbase?

thank you for your help guys. We are currently trying to work out whether we will need to hire a developer or whether something like this could be achieved with a product addons / product variations plugin

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understood your question, but maybe a Woocommerce standard (i.e. comes with Woocommerce) Layered Navigation filter is what you need?
See http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-widgets/